# How to deploy authorization between multiple cakephp applications?

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I have main site example.com where users can register and login or just login with openid.
Logged in users can create their own sites with subdomains like mysite.example.com.
Every user can have multiple sites.
Every site is cakephp app.
Every cake app has its own ACL.

How do I deploy authorization so users logged in to the main site, are also logged in to their own sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two main requirements here:

1. Client-side cookie needs to be valid for all applications

   Check the cookie set by CakePHP on the client side ([FireCookie](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firecookie/) is good for this). The `domain` part of the cookie needs to read `.example.com` (not `www.example.com`) in order for it to apply to sub-domains. This might work in `bootstrap.php`:

   ```
   ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com');
   ```
2. Server-side session storage needs to be accessible by all applications

   In `core.php` for each application, set a common session storage. Options are:

   - `php`: This will use the PHP defined session storage directory, which should be the same for all applications.
   - `database`: If all applications use the same database, this could be an option.
   - `cake`: For this to work, you would need to define a common `/tmp` directory for each application.

Comment: Here are my thoughts. ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com') - for that I think you only need to Configure::write('Security.level', 'low');. As to a 2. (server side), enabling common session storage for all applications means that you would have to controll access to application on application level and that could mess with your ACL. I figured out that the best way would be to store session in database on per application terms and distribute it through out system to other applications that belong to given user.

Comment: can we use common session for 1.3 and 2.x ?

Comment: Should be possible.. `Config/Schema/sessions.php` looks the same in both versions.

Comment: The problem is that i have different cake version for both. I.e. 1.3 & 2.x